# Navigation drawer styles API 8

Tags: android

I have integrated navigation drawer in my app with android-support v7 for minSdkVersion="8" devices. I want to customize navigation bar´s theme but if I use the following code I can´t because requires API level 11, how can I do? Thank you

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/press</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

In particular, look at the `Theme.AppCompat` part.

Answer (score 0):

As you note the parent theme requires API 11. To avoid this use one of the [AppCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.style.html) themes that are included in the v7-support-library, defined in the R.style resource